# Personalizar UINavigationController [código]

Tags: ios, swift

Necesito definir 3 templates de barras de navegación para una app, todas con un mismo color de fondo, una sin botones, otra con un solo botón de retorno en el lazo izquierdo y otra con un botón de retorno (izquierda) y uno de redirección en el lado derecho de la barra.

Personalizacion de colores y aspecto gráfico general

```
class BackNavController: UINavigationController {
override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
    super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    confView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    confView()
}

func confView() {
    navigationBar.barTintColor = Constants.primaryColor
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.barStyle = .black
}
}
```

Para agregar el botón de retorno del segundo template tengo el siguiente codigo dentro del ViewController

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Inicar sesion"
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back-arrow")?.withRenderingMode(.automatic),style: .plain,target: nil,action: #selector(closeView))
    backButton.target = self
    backButton.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

@objc func closeView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

El código funciona, sin embargo el definir los botones dentro de cada ViewController no es la mejor práctica pues debería repetir una y otra vez en cada controllador. La pregunta es cómo podría redefinir este código para poder usarlo cuantas veces sea necesario. Intenté agregar los botones en la subclase BackNavController pero el botón no se muestra.

```
class BackNavController: UINavigationController {
override init(rootViewController: UIViewController) {
    super.init(rootViewController: rootViewController)
    confView()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    confView()
}

func confView() {
    navigationBar.barTintColor = Constants.primaryColor
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "back-arrow")?.withRenderingMode(.automatic),style: .plain,target: nil,action: #selector(closeView))
    backButton.target = self
    backButton.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}

@objc func closeView() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Cómo agregaste los botones que no se ven en esa subclase?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el código solicitado

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar o quitar botones al `Navigation Bar` después de personalizar el `Navigation Controller`, en un proyecto lo tengo así:

En una clase puedes crear una función que te devuelva un `UIButton`

```
static func crearBoton(_ image: String, target: Any, selector: Selector, rect: CGRect?) -> UIButton {
    let newButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    newButton.setImage(UIImage(named: image), for: .normal)
    newButton.addTarget(target, action:selector, for:.touchUpInside)
    
    if let buttonRect = rect {
        newButton.frame = buttonRect
    }
    
    return newButton
}
```

Una función que permita crear los `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
func createItem(target: Any, selector: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let rightButton = crearBoton(imagen: String, target, selector: selector, rect: CGRect)
        
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)
}
```

Otra función para agregar los `UIBarButtonItem` al `NavigationBar`:

```
func addItems(_ type: String, target: Any, selector: Selector) {
    let barItem = createItem(target: target, selector: selector)
    if type == "left" {
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barItem
    } else {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barItem
    }
}
```

En los controller que hereden esa clase y solo llamarías a esa función:

```
class LoginVC: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = "Inicar sesion"
    //Llamas a la función de agregar según lo que necesites
    addItems(_ type: "left", target: Any, selector: selector)
    addItems(_ type: "right", target: Any, selector: selector)
}
```

El `selector` lo defines de acuerdo a la funcionalidad del botón.

El parámetro `CGRect` es opcional y lo puedes omitir.